# Multiple product selector in edit form

Tags: magento2, admin, uicomponent

I'm trying to build a CRUD module for Magento 2.
In this module, one of my entities has a "many to many" relation with the products.
For this, I need to add a section in my add/edit form where I can select the products.
I want to do this using form ui components, not with tabs.
I thought I could replicate the way the related products are done in the product add/edit form.
But there is a problem. I don't understand how is that added to the product form.
From what I saw, the product form uses ui components.
So how is the related products section added to the product edit screen?

Comment: which version are you using? In the current stable release the ui component for inserting a listing into another ui component is not implemented yet, but it should come in 2.1 I think. Maybe it's easier to develop against 2.1 here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Ui/etc/ui_definition.xsd#L72

Comment: I'm using 2.0.something. But there is something implemented for related products. I'm trying to mimic that behavior.

Comment: I would recommend implementing it for 2.1, since the product admin implementation (like many others) changed drastically. Sure it depends when you need this ready. Have a look at the ui_component dir in 2.0 and 2.1: https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.1/app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/adminhtml/ui_component

Comment: I don't need it for now. It is for learning purposes. I was trying to replicate the behavior for reated products but I do not know how this is done.

Comment: in 2.0 it's added pretty oldschool in the Tabs Class: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Edit/Tabs.php#L228 which makes an ajax call on the related controller which loads a block with a serialized grid. I'll bookmark this since I also want to try something like this in 2.1 soon, but currently I don't have the time unfortunately

Comment: just saw this was the 2.1 branch. They implemented the ui components but they seem not to be used yet

Comment: @DavidVerholen the `Tabs` class is there, but it is not used anymore.

Comment: ah ok, good to know :/

Comment: I'm not sure yet, I may have found something in the ui data providers: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/etc/adminhtml/di.xml#L154 https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/Related.php#L259

Comment: You might be on to something. I will start digging from there tomorrow. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the guidance from @DavidVerholen I managed to find out how the related products are added to the product add/edit page.
The ui component must have a data provider class associated to it.
For products this data provider is `Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\ProductDataProvider`.
This is assigned to the ui component in `product_form.xml`

```
<dataSource name="product_form_data_source">
    <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\ProductDataProvider</argument>
        ....
    </argument>
    ....
</dataSource>
```

But this data provider supports modifiers.
each modifier can do 2 things.

- change the configuration of the ui component
- change the data attached to the component.

The product form component has a lot of modifiers attached to it in `adminhtml/di.xml`.
One of these modifiers is the `Related` modifier

```
<virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool" type="Magento\Ui\DataProvider\Modifier\Pool">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
            ....
            <item name="related" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Related</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">110</item>
            </item>
            ...
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\ProductDataProvider">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="pool" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

the modifier for `related` is an instance of `Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Related`.
There are 2 methods in this modifier that are important.

- `modifyMeta`: this one modifies the ui component structure by adding an other fieldset with related products, up-sells and cross-sells.
- `modifyData`: retrieves the related products (and other relations) from the db and attaches the values to the data that should appear in the form.

I guess I could try the same approach on my ui component.

Comment: Is there any way to call my custom phtml in product edit form ? Or any way to use my custom render by using UI component ?  @Marius

Comment: @KeyurShah. I haven't figured that out yet.

Comment: Do you have any reference for that ?, It's too much confusing for me @Marius

Comment: you can take a look at how the [modifiers are added via `di.xml`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/etc/adminhtml/di.xml#L88). Try to add your own modifier and check maybe one of the core modifiers adds a custom phtml to the form.

Comment: Can i add field depends form ui component magento 2 by this